# how to add unique key constraint on column in table in ERD tool in pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, unique-key

I am creating a schema diagram using the ERD tool and want to add a unique key constraint in my column but it seems there is only not null and primary key option is there any idea how to add it?[image]

how to add unique key to the column pan_number and adhare_number in this diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgAdmin dev here. Currently, it is not available.
A ticket is raised - https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/7092 and will be available in future release.

Update: This will be available in pgAdmin 6.8

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Constraints tab
[image]

Comment: This is create table in the database I am int the create ERD diagram section and want to perform this action there

Comment: Ok haven't seen it was in ERD tool. It seems that it's not possible